# Subset string by counting specific characters

Tags: r, regex, gsub, stringr, stringi

I have the following strings:

```
strings <- c("ABBSDGNHNGA", "AABSDGDRY", "AGNAFG", "GGGDSRTYHG")
```

I want to cut off the string, as soon as the number of occurances of A, G and N reach a certain value, say 3. In that case, the result should be:

```
some_function(strings)

c("ABBSDGN", "AABSDG", "AGN", "GGG")
```

I tried to use the `stringi`, `stringr` and regex expressions but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can accomplish your task with a simple call to `str_extract` from the **stringr** package:

```
library(stringr)

strings <- c("ABBSDGNHNGA", "AABSDGDRY", "AGNAFG", "GGGDSRTYHG")

str_extract(strings, '([^AGN]*[AGN]){3}')
# [1] "ABBSDGN" "AABSDG"  "AGN"     "GGG"
```

The `[^AGN]*[AGN]` portion of the regex pattern says to look for zero or more consecutive characters that are not A, G, or N, followed by one instance of A, G, or N. The additional wrapping with parenthesis and braces, like this `([^AGN]*[AGN]){3}`, means look for that pattern three times consecutively. You can change the number of occurrences of A, G, N, that you are looking for by changing the integer in the curly braces:

```
str_extract(strings, '([^AGN]*[AGN]){4}')
# [1] "ABBSDGNHN"  NA           "AGNA"       "GGGDSRTYHG"
```

There are a couple ways to accomplish your task using base R functions. One is to use `regexpr` followed by `regmatches`:

```
m <- regexpr('([^AGN]*[AGN]){3}', strings)
regmatches(strings, m)
# [1] "ABBSDGN" "AABSDG"  "AGN"     "GGG"
```

Alternatively, you can use `sub`:

```
sub('(([^AGN]*[AGN]){3}).*', '\\1', strings)
# [1] "ABBSDGN" "AABSDG"  "AGN"     "GGG"
```

Comment: I don't think it can get much better to the one-liner `str_extract(strings, '([^AGN]*[AGN]){3}')`. Nice one!

Answer (score 9):

Here is a base R option using `strsplit`

```
sapply(strsplit(strings, ""), function(x)
    paste(x[1:which.max(cumsum(x %in% c("A", "G", "N")) == 3)], collapse = ""))
#[1] "ABBSDGN" "AABSDG"  "AGN"     "GGG"
```

Or in the `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
map_chr(str_split(strings, ""), 
    ~str_c(.x[1:which.max(cumsum(.x %in% c("A", "G", "N")) == 3)], collapse = ""))
```

Answer (score 6):

Identify positions of pattern using `gregexpr` then extract n-th position (`3`) and substring everything from `1` to this n-th position using `subset`.

```
nChars <- 3
pattern <- "A|G|N"
# Using sapply to iterate over strings vector
sapply(strings, function(x) substr(x, 1, gregexpr(pattern, x)[[1]][nChars]))
```

PS:

If there's a string that doesn't have 3 matches it will generate `NA`, so you just need to use `na.omit` on the final result.

Comment: Nice! `substr` is vectorized, so I would simplify your last line like this: `substr(strings, 1, map_int(gregexpr(pattern, strings), nChars))`, where `map_int` from **purrr** is used.

Answer (score 2):

This is just a version without `strsplit` to Maurits Evers [neat solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53950398/5193830).

```
sapply(strings,
       function(x) {
         raw <- rawToChar(charToRaw(x), multiple = TRUE)
         idx <- which.max(cumsum(raw %in% c("A", "G", "N")) == 3)
         paste(raw[1:idx], collapse = "")
       })
## ABBSDGNHNGA   AABSDGDRY      AGNAFG  GGGDSRTYHG 
##   "ABBSDGN"    "AABSDG"       "AGN"       "GGG"
```

Or, slightly different, without `strsplit` and `paste`:

```
test <- charToRaw("AGN")
sapply(strings,
       function(x) {
         raw <- charToRaw(x)
         idx <- which.max(cumsum(raw %in% test) == 3)
         rawToChar(raw[1:idx])
       })
```

Answer (score 0):

Interesting problem. I created a function (see below) that solves your problem. It's assumed that there are just letters and no special characters in any of your strings.

```
 reduce_strings = function(str, chars, cnt){

  # Replacing chars in str with "!"
  chars = paste0(chars, collapse = "")
  replacement = paste0(rep("!", nchar(chars)), collapse = "")
  str_alias = chartr(chars, replacement, str) 

  # Obtain indices with ! for each string
  idx = stringr::str_locate_all(pattern = '!', str_alias)

  # Reduce each string in str
  reduce = function(i) substr(str[i], start = 1, stop = idx[[i]][cnt, 1])
  result = vapply(seq_along(str), reduce, "character")
  return(result)
}

# Example call
str = c("ABBSDGNHNGA", "AABSDGDRY", "AGNAFG", "GGGDSRTYHG") 
chars = c("A", "G", "N") # Characters that are counted
cnt = 3 # Count of the characters, at which the strings are cut off
reduce_strings(str, chars, cnt) # "ABBSDGN" "AABSDG" "AGN" "GGG"
```